# Add a string to the thing begin replaced in a case insensitive RegExp.

Tags: javascript, android, regex, webview

sorry for the badly formulated question I hope my text and code will make it better understood what I want to accomplish.

I am Writing some java script for an Android app. I have some problems with the JavaScript RegExp for my webview. Could someone please help me?

Basic pseudo code for what I want to do.

```
/*
* Replace all instances of a letter (case insensitive) with itself + add some string. 
* Example, search for all 'a' (case insensitive) and replace it with 'a 
* someString' if it was lowercase. If it was a capital than replace it with 'A someString' 
*/
```

This is my code (Sorry its all in a string, has to be for the webview).

```
                    "var alpha = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'.split('');" +

                    "for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) " +
                    "{if(window.HtmlViewer.isActive(i))" +
                    "{var re = new RegExp( \"(\" + alpha[i] + \"(?![^<>]*>))\", 'gi' );" +
                    "document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(re, " +
                    "'<font  color=\"'+colorsArray[i]+'\">'+alpha[i]+'</font>');}" +
                    "else{break;}" +
                    "};" +
```

In the first loop it replaces all 'a' and 'A' with 'a' and gives a color to it. What I want is to make it replace 'a' with only 'a' and 'A' with only 'A', i.e. the only thing changing is the color "font  color="'+colorsArray[i]). Any idea how I would accomplish this? Can I somehow use the var re to get if its a capital or lowercase, and than do something like:

```
"'<font  color=\"'+colorsArray[i]+'\">'+re.getString()+'</font>');}" +
```

The solution I have now is to make two for loops and remove the 'i' (case insensitive) modifier. In the first loop I handle lowercase and in the second loop I handle uppercase. But this seems like double work since the color for both 'a' and 'A' are the same. There has to be a better way to do this than that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you don't have to use the loop to match each letter, you can use the regex pattern [a-z] with the 'i' flag to instead of "alpha[i]". I have set up an example that should work for your case here: 
http://jsfiddle.net/yy6we65a/3/

```
var re = /([a-z](?![^<>]*>))/gi;
var colors = ["red","blue","green","yellow","orange"];
var i =0;
function encapsulate(src){
    var ret = '<font color="'+colors[i]+'">'+src+'</font>';    
    i++;
    if( i == 5) i = 0;
    return ret;
}

var orig = document.getElementById("container").innerHTML;
var target = document.getElementById("target");
target.innerHTML = orig.replace(re,encapsulate);
```

I didn't have your color array, so I used one of my own but of course you can just use yours. There are comments in the code to explain each section.